# Can I encourage table-cell text to line wrap?

Tags: html, css, html-table, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I have one entire column of a table who's header consists of a question and in the following rows contains only a checkbox...

```
------------------------------------------------------
| Would you like this text to wrap ? | <rest of row> |     <-- <th>
-------------------------------------+----------------
|                []                  + <rest of row> |     <-- <tr>        
-------------------------------------+----------------
|                []                  + <rest of row> |     <-- <tr>
```

It looks unsightly to me. Can I use any markup to "encourage" browsers to render it like this...

```
---------------------------
| There,  |               |
| isn't   |               |
| that    | <rest of row> |     <-- <th>
| nicer?  |               |
----------+----------------
|   []    |               |     <-- <tr>
----------+----------------
|   []    |               |     <-- <tr>
----------+----------------
```

Please note that I do NOT want to force the browser into a particular rendering, just to suggest something - or to be told that it is not possible.

Any solution must work in MS IE 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the best you can do is giving a width to the chosen `th`

here some example code: http://jsfiddle.net/karameloso/aMTNH/

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see this answer before posting mine.

Comment: @spliter:  Your answer has "teh codez", rather than *just* a link to some site that may disappear before SO does. ;)  So, your answer gets my vote.

Comment: karameloso, that was a hint for you to also paste the critical code into the answer.  SE [frowns on **requiring** a user to follow  links to get the actual answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: +1, but "Please note that I do NOT want to force the browser into a particular rendering, just to suggest something" - that looks liek coercion to me ;-)

Comment: I dunno exactly what u mean with "particular rendering". Anyways, if u don't like this solution, let's wait for a better answer ;)

Comment: Sorry, I think I misiudnerstood.  Lots of +1s to you both and the answer to the first poster. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set width for that column like:

```
table#my-table th:first-child {width: 4em}
```

[Here is an example](http://www.webdevout.net/test?0q)

UPDATE.
Changed px to em's as Brock Adams suggests

Comment: Use `em` or `ex` rather than pixels.  This will adapt to different font sizes (which the user can change at will) better.

Comment: This solution works, but the first-child selector has some issues in IE7. Thats why I usually try to avoid it. See http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=5&cid=1C603

Comment: @karameloso, there is no need to avoid :first-child in your case. Check the up-to-date compatibility table at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html. Your element is not added dynamically, so there is no need to be afraid of this not working in IE7.

Comment: +1, but "Please note that I do NOT want to force the browser into a particular rendering, just to suggest something" - that looks liek coercion to me ;-)

Comment: @Mawg, the solution doesn't force any particular rendering at all in my opinion. Or we define "rendering" differently ;) You could put </br> after every word in the table's header as well but, though, it really doesn't force any specific rendering looks and feels ugly. So, I think the width is the best you can do here :)

Comment: Sorry, I think I misiudnerstood.  Lots of +1s to you both and the answer to the first poster. Thanks.